# Selenium IE11 not responding

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

**Our Manual Scenario is as following:**

- The opened page would ask for a solution name(a textbox).Solution name can be any thing and a solution can be generated with some on cloud constituents.
- Let the name given for solution is "Answer" and hit enter, then the solution start registering on the cloud. Or after writing "Answer" into the text box and click anywhere else , would also effect the same.

**Now Problem is:**
While we are trying to achieve same with automation test script, it is going smooth with Firefox and Chrome. 
But while we are trying on IE11, after putting the solution name onto the text box the UI is not responding anymore.So the solution is not able to start register itself on the cloud.

**The Code is:**

```
waitForPageToLoad(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("SolutionName")));
    WebElement solName= driver.findElement(By.id("SolutionName"));
    sol_Name="Answer";
    solName.sendKeys(sol_Name);//after this line IE is not responding
    solName.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);//In debug mode this line is executing also, but no effect on UI
```

Comment: Hi Friend, Can you please show us your code. This will help us do more...

Comment: @user3872094: code added..please check

Comment: Is it working on IE10? Can you try on that? Try setting nativeEvents as false in the DesiredCapabilities for the IE driver as mentioned in this issue - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4403

Comment: Can you try to focus on the element before by `solName.Click()`?

Comment: @Grasshopper: That nativeEvents is not helping though I set it as 'false'. I need this on IE11+. So didn't try on IE10.

Comment: @kurakura88: How do you expect me to focus? The problem  "solName" is a text box, how can I click a textbox? Isn't it throw an exception? I am able to send solution name through  4th line, but after that it is not reflecting the Enter hitting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move to selenium 3 
it is onle a beta but it should work better 

    org.seleniumhq.selenium
    selenium-ie-driver
    3.0.0-beta2